# How can I run a dedicated Team Arena server using ioquake3 on OS X?

Tags: macos, quake-3

I am trying to get Team Arena to run as a dedicated server on OSX using the [ioquake3 engine](http://ioquake3.org/). I've managed to get Q3 to run okay but not the addon. Everything is installed for Team Arena in the missionpack folder. I tried running the `game_restart missionpack` command but the console says the command can not be found. I also tried adding this to the autoexec.cfg but didn't have any success.

I am running version Q3 1.36.

The OS X is pretty only as it's a spare Xserve running 10.5.8

Can anyone offer some help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, have the solution. I have a shell script with the following:

```
exec /Applications/ioquake3/ioquake3-1.36.app/Contents/MacOS/ioq3ded.ub +set fs_game missionpack
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of attempting to use game_restart, try launching the game with the `+set fs_game` command line parameter (for example `./q3ded +set dedicated 2 +set fs_game missionpack`) specifying the sub folder of the game content you want to use (in this instance `missionpack`).

Comment: I just have 'ioquake2-1.36.app' on OSX so can't find q3ded in the filesystem and not sure if I can pass parameters to a .app

Comment: so do ./ioquakewhatever +set fs_game teamarena

Comment: sorry I misread the foldername you had it installed it, obviously swap out teamarena with missionpack